# systemd-timesyncd: Show NTP status

Tags: linux, systemd, ntp

When using [systemd-timesyncd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-timesyncd), how do you show more detailed NTP status? Specifically, I'm looking for the IP addresses of the peers I'm using (presumably aquired via DHCP).

This does not show what I'm looking for:

```
# timedatectl status
      Local time: Wed 2016-01-13 09:59:13 EST
  Universal time: Wed 2016-01-13 14:59:13 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2016-01-13 14:59:13
       Time zone: America/New_York (EST, -0500)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: no
 Last DST change: DST ended at
                  Sun 2015-11-01 01:59:59 EDT
                  Sun 2015-11-01 01:00:00 EST
 Next DST change: DST begins (the clock jumps one hour forward) at
                  Sun 2016-03-13 01:59:59 EST
                  Sun 2016-03-13 03:00:00 EDT
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
```

this will show you the status of the service and also the accquired IPs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
timedatectl timesync-status
```

or

```
timedatectl show-timesync
```